# How do I get the user number from inside a stackoverflow page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I'm trying to set up a page that (if it were part of stack overflow) would generates a Stackoverflow Flair Blogger Gadget.

Comment: Ummm, there is a /users/XXXX/username link at the top of every page

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question.

If you have to retrieve a user's number from this page with javascript, you should parse the href attribute of the first a element of #hlinks. Mine for example is "/users/recent/112870" where 112870 is my user number.

There might be other ways to do this, this is the first that came to my mind.

Comment: I was kinda hoping for a non string munging solution.

Comment: I looked at js variables but there doesn't seem to be any.
Why would you hoped that, is there a particular reason?